# no default constructor exists for class (c++ classes)

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>

#include<string>

using namespace std;

#ifndef TicTac_H
#define TicTac_H

class TicTac
{
public:
    TicTac(int ,int);
    void setpos(int);
    void getpos(int);
    void setpos2(int);
    void getpos2(int);
    bool takepos();
    void setar(int&, int&);
    void setarr();
    void all(int,int);
    void print();
    int test();

private:
    int p1;
    int p2;
    string tic[3][3] ;
    string x;
    string o;
    int t1;
    int t2;
    bool ok;
};
#endif
```

**The compiler shown this message :
 no default constructor exists for class "TicTac"

'TicTac' : no appropriate default constructor available
 can  anybody help me to fix this problem **

Comment: So add a default constructor - `TicTac();`.

Comment: If you don't create a constructor for a C++ class, the compiler will create a default one for you that accepts no parameters, but if create a constructor and then try to use the "default," you'll get the error you're getting now.  Where's the code that creates a TicTac object.

Comment: You're probably using TicTac in a container or something somewhere, which needs to create TicTac objects with no arguments to the constructor.  So as Captain Obvious said, you need a TicTac().  It's easy enough to just put one in inline:  `TicTac() {}`

Answer (score 3):

The error is surely not in that code, but in the code that includes that header and attempts to create an object of type `TicTac` without providing the two arguments that the constructor takes (two `int`). Other than that, the include guards should cover all the file (including the `#include<...>`) and you should never have a using directive (`using namespace X`) in a header.

Comment: re "you should never have a using directive (using namespace X) in a header", ITYM "in the global namespace in a header".

Comment: @Cheers: personally I believe you should not use them at all, anywhere. Other than that, I don't see anything special about the global namespace here. It is worse in the global namespace, it still isn't good in any other ns. There are exceptions but this is not one of them.

Comment: Oh. I come from the diametrically opposite view about what's ideal, where few if any names are qualified. I think the possibility of mostly using unqualified names is much of the point of namespaces, compared to the C style prefixes or suffixes. Anyway, I guess then it's difficult to agree on the utility (or for that matter dangers) of `using namespace X` in namespaces in headers. So, advice will differ. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Well, I don't particularly like them, but I don't often preach (well, maybe I do) this. On the other hand, in a header you are forcing your options on all of your users, regardless of their preference. Do you want to use it in the implementation file? Inside the definition of a function (whether `inline` in the header or not)… I am fine with it, your code, your choice.

Comment: Well, in header-only modules (very nice for avoiding installation issues) the header is the implementation code. ;-) Apparently diametrically opposed ideals also there. I'd like everything to be in headers, single file per module, although that's not really attainable.

Comment: @Alf: We don't disagree that much, if you carefully read the last comment: *Inside the definition of a function (whether `inline` in the header or not)* — i.e. as long as you don't force your choice on your users. I don't preclude header only libraries or using directives anywhere that you let me have my choice for my own code.